# Getting error with EFS mounting

Tags: amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-efs

Hello I am getting below error when mounting EFS in elastic beanstalk environment.

> 

Command failed on instance. Return code: 1 Output: (TRUNCATED)...iles already exists! mount -t nfs4 -o nfsvers=4.1 us-east-1a.fs-09e50240.efs.us-east-1.amazonaws.com:/ /wpfiles mount.nfs4: Failed to resolve server us-east-1a.fs-09e50240.efs.us-east-1.amazonaws.com: Name or service not known ERROR: Mount command failed!. command 01_mount in .ebextensions/efs-mount.config failed. For more detail, check /var/log/eb-activity.log using console or EB CLI.

> Blockquote

Answer (score 0):

I have figured it out myself, it was an issue with inbound security group on EFS.

Comment: Did you resolve the error? I'm deploying to elastic beanstalk and have not created a EFS, but I'm trying to deploy a Drupal application with eb-php-drupal (a GitHub project for deploying Drupal applications) - is it specific to that type of application? How did you change the inbound security group for EFS?

Comment: @prasoon Why don't you post the solution then?

Comment: The solution was to allow traffic from EC2 security group to EFS on port 2049(NFS).
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/efs/latest/ug/network-access.html